# How to execute the command written in python script in mac terminal immediately after logged in to the server

Tags: python, macos, authentication, ssh, command

```
import os.path
import subprocess
import sys
os.system('sshpass -p password ssh root@esst-warp-d')
subprocess.call('lscpu')
```

I tried the above code, but the command will execute after logging out of the server.

```
import os.path
import subprocess
import sys
os.system('sshpass -p password ssh root@esst-warp-d')
ssh root@esst-warp-d "lscpu"
```

If I try the above code I will get syntax invalid in the fifth line

Can you please help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: You want to execute the command and then stay in the terminal, or execute the command and exit?

Comment: I want to execute the command and stay in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `os.system("sshpass ...")` it creates a new process, unrelated to anything else, and runs your `sshpass` command in it. The process then exits.

When you run `subprocess.call()` it creates a new process, unrelated to the one that just exited above, on your local machine, and runs your command in it. The process then exits.

You actually want to create a new process that connects to the remote Linux machine and then runs a command on there, so you need this:

```
sshpass -p password ssh root@esst-warp-d '/path/to/lscpu'
```

Try it in your Terminal.